# implementing textViewDidChange:

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview

So, I have this very simple list project with objective-c, where every item on the list should have a title and a description. When clicking on one of the items, the detail view of the item shows up. The title, on the navigation bar is the item's title, and the rest of the view is the item's description. By clicking on the title, the user should be able to change it, and by clicking on the description they should also be able to change it.

Up until changing the title everything is going OK, I've managed to do that. The problem is when it comes to changing the description. I tried using the delegate, but I guess I must be using some command wrong, because it's simply not working. I tried looking for it online, but all I find are solutions for the TextField, which doesn't really help me, since I want to display a possibly multiline description, and I would rather not have to change from a TextView to a TextField every time the user wants to edit it. So if anyone could help me out with that, that would be awesome.

Here is the code where I try using the delegate.

on `viewDidLoad` I have this:

```
[self.descriptionLabel setDelegate:self.descriptionLabel.delegate];
```

and then I have this, where it should perform the actions after the text is changed:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSLog(@"Hello World");
}
```

P.S.: I was also looking for a way to have the "Done" button show up over the keyboard, because as of now, once the keyboard is brought up, the only way to get it down again is going back to the table view and then into the detail view again. I tried a couple of things already, but I'll admit that I wasn't too thorough on my research. So, as a side note, if you could show that too, it would be great, otherwise, the one thing I'm really after here is the question above. Thanks for any help! :]

Comment: What is `self.descriptionLabel`? Is that a `UILabel` or a `UITextView`? If the latter, change the name to avoid confusion.

Comment: What's the point of this line: `[self.descriptionLabel setDelegate:self.descriptionLabel.delegate];`? It needlessly sets the delegate to whatever value it already has.

Comment: Most likely you want: `self.descriptionLabel.delegate = self;`.

Comment: Ok, so to the first question, it's a textView, used to be a label, but I changed it, but didn't change the name - I know that's not a smart idea

Comment: what would that second self be? because the first is a "DetailViewController", is that correct?

Comment: The 2nd `self` is the same thing as the 1st `self`. It's the view controller in this case. You want the view controller to be the delegate, right? That's where you implemented the text view delegate method(s).

Comment: it works, but gives me a warning, should I just ignore it or should I do something?

Comment: Never ignore warnings. Always fix them properly. What is the warning?

Comment: Sending 'DetailViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UITextViewDelegate>' - By the way, thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: You need to declare that your view controller conforms to the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Ok, that fixed it, thanks a lot - I'm sorry it was that simple, I'm a beginner to Objective-C and iOS. You should upload your answer so I can mark it as right. Thanks again =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of answer based on the comments.

The line:

```
[self.descriptionLabel setDelegate:self.descriptionLabel.delegate];
```

needs to be:

```
self.descriptionLabel.delegate = self;
```

You want the view controller to be the delegate since the view controller implements the text view delegate methods.

You also need to indicate that the view controller conforms to the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol.

In your .m file, add the following:

```
@interface DetailViewController () <UITextViewDelegate>

@end
```